# Why does creating 2 variables cause a crash in custom STL, C++ VS2019?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, visual-studio-2019

Hello I'm trying to rewrite my own memory manager and STL (nothing fancy, just some basic vector and string features) and I'm getting a strange behaviour. I'm trying to get experience in the memory management field because I'm a high school student with time to spare. The problem is, when I create my first variable everything goes perfectly but after creating the second variable, the program crashes while creating the first variable.

String.h/.cpp

```
    class String {
        char* pointer_toBuffer = nullptr;
        size_t buffer_length = 0;
        IAllocator* Allocator;
    public:
        String(const char* text, IAllocator* Allocator);}

    String::String(const char* text, TuranAPI::MemoryManagement::IAllocator* MemoryAllocator) : Allocator(MemoryAllocator) {
        std::cout << "String creation has started: " << text << std::endl;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while (text[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        buffer_length = i + 1;
        pointer_toBuffer = (char*)Allocator->Allocate_MemoryBlock(buffer_length * sizeof(char));//When I write the Second String part, FirstString crashes directly. I use VSDebug and it says access violation here while creating FirstString. It is successful if I delete the SecondString part.
        for (unsigned int letterindex = 0; letterindex < i; letterindex++) {
            pointer_toBuffer[letterindex] = text[letterindex];
        }
        pointer_toBuffer[i] = 0;
    }
```

MemoryManagement.h/cpp

```
    TAPIMemoryAllocator::TAPIMemoryAllocator(MemoryBlockInfo MemoryPool_toUse){
        std::cout << "TAPIMemoryAllocator is created!\n";
        std::cout << "MemoryPool's start pointer: " << MemoryPool_toUse.address << std::endl;
        MemoryPool.address = MemoryPool_toUse.address;
        MemoryPool.size = MemoryPool_toUse.size;
        SELF = this;
    }
    void* TAPIMemoryAllocator::Allocate_MemoryBlock(size_t size) {
        std::cout << "MemoryPool's start pointer: " << MemoryPool.address << std::endl;
        std::cout << "A buffer of " << size << " bytes allocation request found in TAPIMemoryAllocator!\n";
        if (SELF == nullptr) {
            TMemoryManager First(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1);
            MemoryBlockInfo FirstMemoryBlock;
            FirstMemoryBlock.address = SELF->MemoryPool.address;
            FirstMemoryBlock.size = size;
            Allocated_MemoryBlocks[0] = FirstMemoryBlock;
            return (char*)SELF->MemoryPool.address;
        }
        void* finaladdress = SELF->MemoryPool.address;
        for (unsigned int blockindex = 0; blockindex < MAX_MEMORYBLOCKNUMBER; blockindex++) {
            MemoryBlockInfo& MemoryBlock = Allocated_MemoryBlocks[blockindex];
            finaladdress = (char*)finaladdress + MemoryBlock.size;
            if (size <= MemoryBlock.size && MemoryBlock.address == nullptr) {
                std::cout << "Intended block's size is less than found memory block!\n";
                MemoryBlock.address = finaladdress;
                //You shouldn't change Memory Block's size because all of the allocations before this are based upon the previous size!
                //You should move all the previous allocated memory to set the size (which is not ideal!)
                //If I'd want to find memory leaks causing this, I could write code here to log the leaks!
                return MemoryBlock.address;
            }
            else if (MemoryBlock.size == 0 && MemoryBlock.address == nullptr) {
                std::cout << "An empty block is created for intended block! Block's Array index is: " << blockindex << "\n";
                std::cout << "MemoryPool's start pointer: " << MemoryPool.address << std::endl << "MemoryBlock's pointer: " << finaladdress << std::endl;
                //This means this index in the Allocated_MemoryBlocks has never been used, so we can add the data here!
                MemoryBlock.address = finaladdress;
                MemoryBlock.size = size;
                return MemoryBlock.address;
            }
        }
        //If you arrive here, that means there is no empty memory block in the Allocated_MemoryBlocks array!
        std::cout << "There is no empty memory block in the Allocated_MemoryBlocks array, so nullptr is returned!\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    TMemoryManager::TMemoryManager(size_t Main_MemoryBlockSize) {
        if (SELF != nullptr) {
            std::cout << "You shouldn't create a MemoryManager!";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "TMemoryManager is created!\n";
        MainMemoryBlock.address = malloc(Main_MemoryBlockSize);
        MainMemoryBlock.size = Main_MemoryBlockSize;
        SELF = this;
        std::cout << "Main Memory Block's start pointer: " << MainMemoryBlock.address << std::endl;

        MemoryBlockInfo TuranAPI_MemoryPool;
        TuranAPI_MemoryPool.address = MainMemoryBlock.address;
        std::cout << "TuranAPI_MemoryPool.address: " << TuranAPI_MemoryPool.address << std::endl;
        TuranAPI_MemoryPool.size = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
        TAPIMemoryAllocator Create(TuranAPI_MemoryPool);
    }
    TMemoryManager* TMemoryManager::SELF = nullptr;
    TMemoryManager First(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1);
```

Main.cpp

```
String FirstString("How are you?", TAPIMemoryAllocator::SELF);
std::cout << FirstString << std::endl; //If I delete the below, it prints "How are you?" as expected
String SecondString("I'm fine, thanks!", TAPIMemoryAllocator::SELF);
std::cout << SecondString << std::endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`FirstString` fail to create"? What is `TuranAPI::MemoryManagement::TAPIMemoryAllocator::SELF`? Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] (with emphasis on both the minimal and complete parts). Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed them. I didn't want to add them because post is getting longer and the debug's report is not about Allocator. If SecondString is coded in main.cpp VSDebug says there is an access violation while creating FirstString. If I delete the SecondString part of main.cpp, there is no error and it prints How Are You? as expected

Comment: ***and the debug's report is not about Allocator*** I think it is. Your original code did not appear to have a bug that was easily visible in the code. However you new code appears that I would have to use my debugger to figure it out. I still think the bug is in your Allocator.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to know the difference between your debugger and mine if we can solve this. My knowledge about debugging doesn't afford my needs sometimes, especially in my Vulkan renderer. The reason I started to experience memory management was the renderer's different behaviour every time it runs. Thought creating a memory system would help me.

Comment: It would be the same debugger. Although I have debugged code since 1982 and professionally since 1997. You need to set breakpoints and step through the code line by line. You need to know what the F9, F10 and F11 keys do those are the most important ones in Visual Studio. And if your experiences an access violation in some code that is not yours walk up the callstack to your code using the Stack Frame on the Visual Studio toolbar.

Comment: You *do* have bugs in the allocator: `if (SELF == nullptr) { ... FirstMemoryBlock.address = SELF->MemoryPool.address; ... }`

Comment: I may be wrong about `SELF = this;` however it is a concern when I try to follow the code in my head. I can't help now. Have a virtual meeting later today for the paying job.

Comment: Oh, it's the thing I think @drescherjm . I will try to do something different, but I didn't think like that because every variable of TMemoryManager and TAPIMemoryAllocator is static. But it's virtual function Allocate_MemoryBlock and Delete_MemoryBlock's are probably deleted after scope. I let the program delete the Allocator because I couldn't use new (because new is depend on allocator), probably need to memcpy or something. I'd like to hear your idea. And also, I didn't mean to underestimate your knowledge; sorry if it sounds like that. Btw, good luck in your meeting!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it isn't the problem, because it's never executed in the current program. It may be a problem if I use new before creating the allocator. That's not the in the current program, I used cout to confirm it's not executed.
I will try to fix the problem like I said before. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem was in Allocator. When allocator goes out of scope, it's Allocate_MemoryBlock function (it's a virtual function, not static) is deleted. I don't know why it doesn't occur when only one String is created (maybe a compiler optimization) but storing Allocator's itself (All of variables was static already) and assinging SELF as stored one's pointer solved the problem.

Comment: When you have Undefined Behavior one of the most unfortunate behaviors is the code working as expected giving you a false sense that the code is correct.

Comment: Be careful of static initialization order fiasco.